# Forecasting in ML with XGBoost ( tricky time series)

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, xgboost, forecasting

I have a dataset with daily observations of sales for 1000 company shops during the last 3 years(of course apart from the sales figure alone, I've got features like: promotions, shop type, assortment type etc.)

The goal is to build a model to predict future sales. How would you build a model from 1000 time series and generalize it such that it could be used to predict sales for 1 shop with certain features?

The dataset is similar to : https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/notebooks.

Basing on the solutions (in python) for this dataset provided on Kaggle, I noticed that nearly everyone is using XGBoost, but I have some doubts regarding these solutions that were provided and I'd be thankful for some clarification. In particular:

1. How can people just load the data with daily observations for over 1000 shops for 3.5 years for each shop to the model, without one-hot encoding the store id's first? Isn't the model going to fail at some point because it will learn that shop #1040 is better than shop #35 - just because of shop id?
2. If we would use traditional one-hot encoding this would create 1000 new columns which is unmanageable - but nevertheless is there a way of solving this problem with one-hot encoding?
3. Why are people extracting the "date" feature by adding : day,week,month as separate variables? Isn't that misleading to the model? Why aren't people assigning the "date" as an index instead?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is better suited for stats.stackexchange.com. SO is for well-defined *programming* questions.

Comment: Your question may be moved or closed, hence here is my opinion to help you anyways. 1.&2. It is completely up to you whether you want to have store as a variable. Store x being better than store y can serve as a proxy of a ton of hidden geographical attributes. The only way in Python is to one-hot encode, while R takes care of it for you if you declare it as a categorical variable. Of course memory usage increases and the tradeoff is yours. 3. To capture seasonalities at the level of day of the week, week of the month and month of the year.

Answer (score -1):

- 1 - [This](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-gradient-boosting-xgboost-python/)  explains data prepration for XGBoost. You could be hurting the models ability of learning by not one-hot encoding, but it seems like you have enough features that your model can still learn the correct correlations.
- 2 - You pretty much answer this question yourself. The one-hot encoding approach would explode the number of features you have, overwhelming the model, slowing the training process and worst of all it might not help that much
- 3 - This is a common feature engineering approach to give me the model more information to work with while not completely overshadowing other features. For ex. Store A might have sales on Monday at 5 most of the time.

Basically you have to try it to see if it works.
Im sure your fellow Kagglers have tried many more combinations of feature engineering, one-hot encoding categorical data, different model and many more.

Comment: if that's everything you please accept do this question can be closed